# React Native - Nodejs Express Social Login

Tags: react-native, facebook-login, google-signin

I have been pulling my hair to understand what is the method to implement facebook/google login for a react native mobile application which has a nodejs back end.

I currently have social login properly working for reactjs website, which is using passport.js.
In the website, clicking facebook/google login buttons calls my server API. From server API request is redirected to Facebook which provides a form for the client to login. Once the user is authenticated, Facebook shares the requested user info to node js server and the server returns the JWT to the mobile application.

How can I port this method to react-native mobile application?

Any help is highly appreciated!!